# How can i resolve loop in one to many relationship .netcore

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, relationship, webapi

I have in .net core 7 a webapi project with mysql DB, and when I do a one to many relation, work only in one direciton. In other direction i have a loop problem.

This is one model, with same Dto

```
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }

        //NAVIGATION
        public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
     }
```

This is second model

```
    public class Project
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }
     }
```

The model and the dto are the same.

How can I make the relationship work both ways without loop issues?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the code, but I believe it should be sufficient to read data from both the User and Project models, as it includes the necessary methods to retrieve related entities in both directions of the one-to-many relationship.

Read Projects data from the User model:

```
int userId = 1;
var userWithProjects = dbContext.Users
    .Include(u => u.Projects)
    .SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);

if (userWithProjects != null)
{
    foreach (var project in userWithProjects.Projects)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Project ID: {project.Id}, Name: {project.Name}, Description: {project.Description}");
    }
}
```

Read User data from the Project model:

```
int projectId = 1;
var projectWithUser = dbContext.Projects
    .Include(p => p.User)
    .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == projectId);

if (projectWithUser != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Project ID: {projectWithUser.Id}, Name: {projectWithUser.Name}, Description: {projectWithUser.Description}, User ID: {projectWithUser.UserId}");

    if (projectWithUser.User != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"User ID: {projectWithUser.User.Id}, Email: {projectWithUser.User.Email}, Role: {projectWithUser.User.Role}");
    }
}
```